# Presentation of the shift-replace monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, group-presentation

Let

\begin{align}
    S(f)(x) &= f(x + 1) \\
    R_a(f)(x) &= \begin{cases}
        a       & x = 0 \\
        f(x)    & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

What is the [presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_monoid) of the [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) [generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(mathematics)) by $\{S, S^{-1}\} \cup \{R_a \mid a \in A\}$ under [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)? Is it the following?

\begin{align}
    S S^{-1} &= 1 \\
    S^{-1} S &= 1 \\
    R_a R_b &= R_a
 \\
    (S^n \cdot R_a) R_b &= R_b (S^n \cdot R_a) & n \neq 0
\end{align}

where $a \cdot b = a b a^{-1}$ denotes [conjugation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conjugation+action). The last relation entails

\begin{align}
(S^m \cdot R_a) (S^n \cdot R_b) &= (S^n \cdot R_b) (S^m \cdot R_a) & m \neq n
\end{align}

Are there other relations? Can it be made [finitely related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Definition)?

**Edit:** I think the following is a normal form for this monoid:

\begin{align}
&S^m \prod_i (S^{n_i} \cdot R_{a_i}) & i < j \Rightarrow n_i < n_j
\end{align}

Comment: It makes no sense to use the commutator in this context, though you can rewrite that equation to not use it. Also the $n=0$ case of your second equation is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. If I specify $n \neq 0$, would that fix the problem?

Comment: It fixes that particular issue, but $S^{-1}$ (similarly for arbitrary negative $n$) is not a generator. You need to add $S^{-1}$ to your generating set and the relations to make it behave as its name suggests, i.e. $SS^{-1} = id$ and $S^{-1}S = id$.

Comment: Assuming you want to allow that (i.e. representations of $f \mapsto (x\mapsto f(x-1)))$. If not you need to reformlate the second equation to not rely on $S$ to negative powers.

Comment: Right, I forgot that generators include inverses in the context of a group but not a monoid (since e.g. $R_a$ does not have an inverse). If you would like to continue discussing in chat, I would be happy to.

Comment: My suggestion (not saying it will work) on how to approach proving the statement and to get some idea of what laws are necessary, would be to consider a normal form and consider what equations would allow you to reach that normal form. A promising possibility is $S^{n_{k+1}}(R_{a_k}S^{n_k})\cdots (R_{a_1}S^{n_1})$ where the $n_i$ are strictly increasing with $i$. This is in the context where $S^{-1}$ is disallowed, but a similar normal form candidate would work if that is allowed.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, like a machine that starts at the leftmost position and moves to the right while writing down the appropriate symbols.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58704/discussion-between-carlos-and-derek-elkins).

Comment: Yes, the normal form you suggest is a normal form indeed. (To see that the $m$, $n_i$ and $a_i$ are uniquely determined, it suffices to notice that the $m$ is uniquely determined as the amount by which the function is shifted at all but finitely many points; that the $n_i$ are uniquely determined as the positions at which the values of the function are replaced; and that the $a_i$ are uniquely determined as the values of replacement.) Moreover, you can bring every element of the monoid to such a normal form by using only the relations you gave. Thus, the presentation you gave ...

Comment: ... is indeed a presentation. Of course, this doesn't answer the question whether there is a finitely related presentation.